# Docker: Issues establishing PostgreSQL connection in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I have been researching this for a couple of days now and I am finally at a point where I decided to get help. I am trying to spin up a simple Docker image running a Rails application using the quite popular [Phusion Passenger Docker image](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker) as my base image. The issue lies in establishing a connection to the PostgreSQL database.

Here is my `database.yml` file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  user: pguser
  password: pguser
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  encoding: utf8
  port: 5432

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
```

I am trying to build the image with this `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use phusion/passenger-full as base image. To make your builds reproducible, make
# sure you lock down to a specific version, not to `latest`!
# See https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker/blob/master/Changelog.md for
# a list of version numbers.
FROM phusion/passenger-full:0.9.18

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Use baseimage-docker's init process.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# ...put your own build instructions here...

RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down

# Expose Nginx HTTP service
EXPOSE 80

# Remove the default site
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# Add the nginx site and config
ADD myapp.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf
ADD rails-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/rails-env.conf

###### Andrea Grandi https://github.com/andreagrandi/postgresql-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile ######

# Add the PostgreSQL PGP key to verify their Debian packages.
# It should be the same key as https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

# Add PostgreSQL's repository. It contains the most recent stable release
#     of PostgreSQL, ``9.3``.
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Update the Ubuntu and PostgreSQL repository indexes and install ``python-software-properties``,
# ``software-properties-common`` and PostgreSQL 9.3
# There are some warnings (in red) that show up during the build. You can hide
# them by prefixing each apt-get statement with DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y -q install python-software-properties software-properties-common \
    && apt-get -y -q install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

USER postgres

RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start \
    && psql --command "CREATE USER pguser WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'pguser';" \
    && createdb -O pguser myapp_production

USER root

# Adjust PostgreSQL configuration so that remote connections to the
# database are possible.
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

# And add ``listen_addresses`` to ``/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf``
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql && chown -R postgres /var/run/postgresql

# Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]

USER postgres

# Set the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf"]

###### /Andrea Grandi https://github.com/andreagrandi/postgresql-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile ######

USER root

# Add the Rails app
RUN mkdir /home/app/MyApp
WORKDIR /home/app/MyApp
ADD . /home/app/MyApp
RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/MyApp

# Install bundle of gems
RUN apt-get install pkg-config
RUN apt-get install libgmp-dev
RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle install

# run migrations
RUN RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate --trace
RUN rake db:seed

#enable memcached
#RUN rm -f /etc/service/memcached/down

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Then, when I run `docker run .` in my app directory I get the following error:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Can you login to your container and verify that postgres is running?

Comment: Good one! I'll try that

Comment: @warmoverflow Sorry for taking so long, haven't been able to test your suggestion, but I am strangely getting an error upon running the docker image that says: `"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.`. I am not sure what to do about this, as I am clearly switching to the `postgres` user when starting the postgres server. Any ideas ?

Comment: Not sure, but I am thinking that it is a lot easier to just use a standalone PostgreSQL image (like the official one), instead of integrating it into your own container.

Comment: So should I access the database across containers ? Postgres in one and Rails app in second [container] ?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty easy. There are actually examples on the postgres image page https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: Looking at that right now, sounds like a nice solution (+ decoupling). I'll get back to you shortly how that went. Thanks for the support up to this point, appreciate it.

Comment: Okay, got the Postgres container running, how do I now migrate my database to that ? I understand that I need to link the app container to the postgres container, but what makes the app container know to use the postgres container as the store ?

Comment: I assume I'll need to specify the ip address of the postgres container in my `database.yml` for my host ? Will that do the trick ?

Comment: If you followed the instructions on the postgres image page, gave the container a name and linked it to your rails container, you can just specify the host as `container_name` in `your database.yml`

Comment: @warmoverflow I finally got it working after countless hours of research, trial and error. While your suggestion was not exactly the solution to my problem, it guided me into the right direction. If you write up an answer summarizing your suggestions I'd be willing to reward you. Thanks.

Comment: That's all right. But if my suggestion was not exactly the solution, you can write an answer yourself so that it may help people in the future. I am happy as long as you acknowledge my input.

Comment: I'll do that for sure. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: thanks guys for the wonderful yet hidden answer. took me a couple of hours to find this answer

Comment: what is the answer? Help. Please don't make this a 'hidden' answer.

Comment: @DavidWest I'll try to write up an answer now.